# Is there a way to find end token

Tags: python, nlp, token, spacy

I am trying to find out if the token is last one in Spacy doc. I don't want to iterate over the doc, but need to check based on position of the token if the token is last token. Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare it with the length of the spaCy `Doc`. E.g. let's print all tokens with their indices and indicate when it's the last one.

```
import spacy

str = "the big brown fox"
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp(str)

for i, t in enumerate(doc):
    print("{}{}: {}".format(i, " and last" if i == len(doc) - 1 else "", t.text))
```

Result:

```
0: the
1: big
2: brown
3 and last: fox
```

Comment: Thank you but this solution does not necessarily work for me. I need to determine if a token is last token in the doc. Suppose the doc is str = "the big brown fox and brown fox". I should be able to identify that 'fox' is last token only when I am at second fox

Comment: @MLNLPEnhusiast that should still work since we're comparing indices rather than words.

Answer (score 0):

```
test_str = "which string is the last"
doc = nlp(test_str)
doc[len(doc)-1:len(doc)]
```